# Poisson integral satisfying boundary value condition

Tags: integration, homogeneous-equation

If the Poisson integral is
$$\int\int_S P(r,r')u_0(r')dr'$$
And gives the solution to the boundary value conditions
$\Delta u(r)=0$ for |r|<1 and $u=u_0$ for |r|=1
The Poisson kernel being $$P(r,r')=\frac1{4\pi} \frac{1-|r|^2}{|r'-r|^3}$$

How would one go about proving that $$\int\int_S P(r,r')dr'=1$$ if |r|<1?

Comment: Hint: If $u_0\equiv1$, what is the solution to the boundary value problem?

Comment: The Hint helped and we managed to solve it. Thanks.